# Handling ItemClick or Click in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, events, click, xamarin.android, xamarin

I'm trying to make a handler for ItemClick or Click in Xamarin Android Mono project.

My code:

```
_widgets.DepartureSpinner.ItemClick += delegate (object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs args) {
        // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
        Toast.MakeText (Application, ((TextView)args.View).Text, ToastLength.Short).Show ();
    }
```

Leads to

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: setOnItemClickListener cannot be used with a spinner.
```

Pretty same with Click.
I don't want to use custom button because it won't change with theme change.
There are topics on how to do it in java, but I can't get how to do it in Xamarin.

Comment: AFAIK use setOnItemSelectedListener instead of setOnItemClickListener for spinner.

Comment: This is not possible in mono for android without intrusion to java interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

use `setOnItemSelectedListener` instead of `setOnItemClickListener` for spinner.